# How can I suggest to a person that they combine both their answers to make a complete answer to my question?

Tags: discussion, answers, self-answer

I have recently posted a question [How to string count unique values in data strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65922063/how-to-string-count-unique-values-in-data-strings)
on how to deal with string data variables.

Someone has answered in **an ambiguous and incomplete way** to my question, but at the end they posted **another separate answer** that revealed to me what they meant. The combination of both their answers is a perfect response to my question.

I wonder, how can I suggest to that person that they combine their answers so that I can accept it?

Is there an accepted, appropriate way to do this?

Comment: I don't see anybody having posted 2 answers. Do you count the *comment* under your question as an answer? You might ask them to update their answer in a comment, maybe below their answer asking them to add the info from their comment to their answer.

Comment: kindly check that one named **deschen**
he/she started saying that the problem I have is >5 which I thought was not correct, but after showing his/her code. I found that he/she was correct. thanks!

Comment: They posted 1 comment and 1 answer. See for more info: [What are comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Comment: Ohh! I see, it's me who had no info on how to distinguish comment from answer. thanks a lot for your clarification with my vote!

Comment: I included the information from the comment into the answer in order to turn it into a self-contained post. Hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. thank you indeed!

Answer (score 20):

You are confusing [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) for an answer.

The user [deschen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2725773/deschen) first posted a (now deleted) comment under your question. Then, they elaborated to [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65922198/6045800).

If you think the information from the comment is helpful and missing from the answer, you can do 2 things:

1. ***Comment*** under the question and tag the user (by `@deschen`) or under the answer, and suggest them to add that comment into the answer.
2. SO is supposed to be an open "encyclopedia" curated by the community itself. You can ***propose an edit*** to the answer and hope that deschen (or other high-rep users) will see it and accept.

---

Right now, @honk already edited the comment into the answer so now it is complete.